# Is there a way to figure out the $n$ such that $n!$ ends with exactly $k$ zeroes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given $n$, I can find the number of zeroes at the end of the decimal representation of $n!$ by
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{n}{5^i}\right\rfloor.
$$

Is there a way to reverse this? That is, given $k$, is there a way to find out how many $n$ exist such that $n!$ has exactly $k$ zeroes at the end of its decimal representation besides making educated guesses and checking them?

Answer (score 2):

There's a way to almost reverse this. I find it easier to think about this in terms of quinary (base $5$) representations. So your formula says that the number of zeroes in the decimal representation of $n!$ is the sum of all right-shifted and truncated versions of the quinary representation of $n$. That means that the $m$-th digit $a_m$ of the quinary representation of $n$ contributes

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}5^i=\frac{5^m-1}4
$$

zeroes, so we have

$$
4k=\sum_m a_m5^m-\sum_ma_m=n-\sum_ma_m\;.
$$

So $n$ is basically $4k$, and then you have to adjust a bit because the sum of the quinary digits gets subtracted.

Comment: You use $z$ where the question uses $k$ and then you $k$ for something else.

Comment: Also the question asks "how many" values of $n$ there are for a given $k$, not what these values are. But it seems likely one won't be able to answer "how many" (even though that's bound to be either $4$ or $0$) without knowing which values of $n$ give something close to $k$.

Comment: @Henry: Thanks; I hate it when people do that! ;-) Fixed.

Comment: @Marc: You're right; though in "Is there a way to reverse this", "this" refers to $k$ expressed as a function of $n$, so that part of the question does at least implicitly ask for something like $n$ as a function of $k$.

Comment: Thanks Joriki. How do you get to $4k=\sum_m a_m5^m-\sum_m a_m$? I don't understand why the $\sum_m a_m$ parts appeared.

Comment: @Laura: I multiplied the first equation by $4a_m$ and summed over $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the amount of information in [OEIS A027868](http://oeis.org/A027868) and [OEIS A007845](http://oeis.org/A007845), you may not be able to do much better than an educated guess.

Your first educated guess might be to look at $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{n}{5^i}=\frac{n}{4}.$$  But using $4k$ will be too low, because of rounding.

How far too low?

Note that if $k=776$ then $n=3120 = 4 \times 776 +16$ (or $3121,3122,3123,3124$)

while if $k=781$ then $n=3125 = 4 \times 781+1$ (or the next four).

If $4k+1$ is just below a multiple of a large power of $5$ then the amount you have to add on will be greater than if $4k+1$ is equal to or just above a multiple of a large power of $5$, but I suspect it may be quicker to do this by experiment than to seek a formula.

Answer (score -1):

This is wrong:

Well, a number is going to have as many 0's at the end as it has factors of 10 in it, and since $n!$ is going to have an abundance of 2's, you only need to look for 5's. So every time you hit a $n$ that is divisible by 5, $n!$ gains another 0. So there are 5 n such that $n!$ has k 0's. Specifically, $n = 5k,\, 5k+1,\, 5k+2,\, 5k+3,\, 5k+4$

At least I'm pretty sure I'm right, but I have no experience with number theory.

Why it is wrong: 25! has 2 5s, so does 50!, 75!; 125! has 3 etc. ie, Problems with higher powers of 5. But you will have either 5 or 0 n for any k.

Comment: You're taking about the formula already given in the question. The question was how to invert it.

Comment: @joriki "given k, is there a way to find out how many n exist such that n! has exactly k zeroes at the end of its decimal representation" I say there are 5 such n and that they are 5k to 5k+4

Comment: But $n!$ gains two zeros when $n$ hits $25$, not one.

Comment: That is too high.  $25!$ has $6$ trailing zeros

Comment: So there will either be 0 or 5 n? And there won't be any n for k=5, 11, 17, 6i-1 until you hit n = 125 right?